# How to make dynamic menu toggleable primefaces 4.0

Tags: java, primefaces

im following the tutorial for dynamic menu from

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menu.xhtml

im trying to make the sub menu toggleable.

```
<p:menu model="#{menuView.model}" style="width:180px" toggleable="true"/>
```

but its not working. is it any other way to do it?

Comment: Please attach the html form element at least and the backing bean. Also which version of primefaces and jsf implementation are you using?

Comment: have you tried to put it inside a <form> tag

Comment: also check with another browser (maybe ajax is not enabled in your browser).

Comment: the code is exactly same as example. i just trying to make the dynamic menu toggleable. @NPE i already tried but still not working

Comment: @puyen do you get any errors ?

Comment: @NPE no error. do you have any other ways? im still new with primefaces. btw im using jsf 2.2 and primefaces 4.0

Comment: you use exactly the same code provided in this page http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menu.xhtml You don't see any prime components or it is just toggle able feature that is not working?

Comment: im using only "Programmatic Menu" part in that page. yes. only toggle able feature that is not working. @NPE

Comment: try the toggle-able sample, remove all the action listeners and update and outcome attributes also put the whole thing in a form tag just like the sample